# Change the elements of list of lists based on condition

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have the following nested list:

```
original = [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O']]
```

There are only three kind of elements in the original list, i.e., `B_S`,`I_S`,and `O`.
I want to change the elements based on a a specific condition:
If an elements starts with **B-prefix** (i.e., B_S) the following element should be changed to start with **I-prefix** if it had **B-prefix**.
The desired output in this case is:

```
desired = [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'I_S', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'I_S', 'B_S', 'O']]
```

It worked with this solution:

```
for ls in original:
    for i in range(0,len(ls)):
        if ls[i] == 'B_S' and ls[i+1] == 'B_S':
            ls[i+1] = 'I_S'
```

But it takes a long time with a large dataset... is there any way to improve the code performance?

Comment: You could use a counter instead of a `range()` and increment it extra when modifying `i+1`

Comment: @ti7 how would that improve performance?

Comment: They avoid re-testing entries they just changed

Comment: try converting list to string using `join()` then you can use `replace()` to make the change

Comment: A more performant way may depend on the data. For example if there are many more 0s than other values it might make sense to store the data very differently, for example instead of a list, just track the number of elements and which indexes have a "B_S" and which an "I_S". Also if the lists never go over say 32 elements, you could store the data as two 32 bit integers, one a bit mask for the "B_S" positions one for the "I_S" positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os


original = [['B_S', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O', 'O'],
            ['O', 'B_S', 'O', 'O', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'B_S', 'O']]


def change(sub_list):
    len_ = len(sub_list)
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < len_:
        if sub_list[cnt] == 'B_S' and sub_list[cnt+1] == 'B_S':
            sub_list[cnt+1] = 'I_S'
        cnt += 1
    return sub_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []
    for result in Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()).map(change, original[:]):
        results.append(result)
    print(results)
```

This will just spilt your original list into sublists, and treat them each individually before combining them back together.

This can for sure be further improved, as other comments already suggested.

Comment: Using the multithreading is not a performance improvement. It's just using extra resources to complete the task in less time

Comment: I know, I was just trying to provide a solution focused on time, since that was what OP seemed to worry most about.